# Update flags for a window

Tags: c++, linux, xlib

Good morning everyone!  I am trying to set and (later) delete a flag for a window in C++.  No matter what I try to do, I continue to get compile errors and can't figure it out.  Below are the relevant bits of the the object:

```
enum {
    NO_FOCUS        = 0x0001,
    CLICK_TO_FOCUS      = 0x0002,
    NO_BORDER       = 0x0004,
 ...
}

class Frame : public Fl_Window {
    int flags_;
    void set_flag(int i) {flags_ |= i;}
    void clear_flag(int i) {flags_&=~i;}
    int flags() const {return flags_;}
    int flag(int i) const {return flags_&i;}
 ...
}
```

I am trying to adjust the flags value from another function:

```
void ShowWindow() {
 Display* d = fl_display;
 XWindow w = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, RootWindow(d, fl_screen),
        0, 0,
  100, 200,
        0,
        0x000000,
        0x000000);

    Frame* frame = new Frame(w);
 //frame.flags |= NO_BORDER;
 //frame->flags() |= NO_BORDER;
 frame->flags(NO_BORDER);
}
```

I have tried other ways than the commented out parts above, but no matter what I try, I continue to get compile errors.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Dave

UPDATE:

Per the information provided, I have made the set_flag() function public, but am not getting the desired results.  Another function in the project checks the value of the flags before drawing the window:

```
void Frame::updateBorder() {
 ...

    if (flag(NO_BORDER)) { ... }
 else { ... }
}
```

But it doesn't appear that when I set the flag externally, this is getting triggered. And after adding some debug printf statements, I can see that the window is being draw before the flag can be set.  How can I resolve that?  Would I have to do something like:

```
Frame*->set_flag(NO_BORDER);
Frame* frame = new Frame(w);
```

or

```
Frame* frame;
frame->set_flag(NO_BORDER);
frame = new Frame(w);
```

I can get the program to compile with the latter, but the desired effects are still not happening.  How can I set the flag before the window is drawn?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Is `ShowWindow()` a member of `Frame`?

Comment: @NathanOliver No, ShowWindow() is just a function I created in the .cpp file.

Comment: Here `Frame* frame; frame->set_flag(NO_BORDER);` you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. What happens then is undefined. If you are lucky, your program will crash exactly where you do it. This and your other "attempts" make it looks like you don't know C++ at all and are just trying to get the code to compile. Compiling doesn't mean it is correct. You can't write a C++ program that do what you want by random guesses.

Comment: @Leiaz you are correct to an extent.  As specified in another post which you helped with, I had a project dumped in my lap.  I have programmed for over two decades, just not in C++. Portions of this are unfamiliar which is why I'm asking for help after doing research before asking questions. I do appreciate all the help everyone has provided, but don't be surprised to see another question or two popup!

Comment: @leias would you be interested in helping with the portions I don't know? :)

Comment: I can at least try to explain what I find unclear. If `Fl_Window` is the [FLTK window widget](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Window.html), your `ShowWindow` function is creating two windows. `Fl_Window` has a `border` function that seem to do what you want ? And a GUI toolkit like FLTK is usually used to avoid calling xlib directly. So you should perhaps add a line or two of context to your question, to explain the bigger picture of what you are doing. Also in the previous question, by window manager I meant [X window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_window_manager).

Answer (score 0):

You need `public:` before the part(s) of your class that you want accessible from outside the class.

Notice you ought not to make flags_ public, so you ought not to make this form usable:

```
frame.flags_ |= NO_BORDER;
```

and flags without the underscore is a function, so the following that you tried is badly wrong:

```
frame.flags |= NO_BORDER;
```

You defined flags() to be very much read only, so even when you make flags public, you can't do:

```
frame->flags() |= NO_BORDER;
```

Once you make the correct part of the class public, you should use it as defined:

```
frame->set_flag( NO_BORDER );
```

Comment: Thanks JSF, won't I get a bunch of errors if I change those aspects from private to public?

Comment: What errors do you expect?  Try it and see.  Maybe I'm missing your point, but the design of that class clearly makes best sense if the only private thing (among those you showed) is the data member.  The functions you showed all make sense to be public.

Comment: I made the set_flag() function public and was able to compiled the software, however, I don't see that the desired effects are taking place...  I'm trying to create a window without a border and another function.  I will edit my original post to include that info.